# Quitar un plus dependiendo cuanto meses indique

Tags: php, mysql

me veo con el siguiente problema y no le doy solución, el problema es que tengo una tabla siniestros en la cual se van introduciendo los siniestros que tienen los trabajadores, en el cual se introduce `FechaSiniestro - Trabajador - MesesCastigo` y lo que quiero es que al imprimir las nóminas todos los meses que tenga marcados se le vaya quitando un plus, por ejemplo:

```
        //AÑADIMOS LA FUNCIONALIDAD DE QUITAR EL PLUS CONSERVACION SI TIENE ALGUN SINIESTRO
        $query = "SELECT MIN(FechaSuceso),SUM(MesesPlus) AS MesesPlus FROM siniestros WHERE CodTrabajador=$codtrab";
        $result = mysqli_query($conection, $query);
        $mesesplus=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $conservacion = $total - $descuentoconservacion;
        $totalconservacion = round($conservacion * $empresaconservacion / $totaldiasmes, 2);

        if ($mesesplus['MesesPlus']>0){
            $conservacion=0;
            $totalconservacion=0;
        }
```

Pero tengo el problema que si filtro la consulta a partir de la fecha actual, si en un mes anterior tiene varios meses de castigo ya se pierden, y la verdad estoy un poco perdido, a ver si alguien con mas coco que yo me puede ayudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer las búsquedas de fechas con un intervalo de x meses. Te añado un ejemplo para preguntar que trabajadores están en periodo punible por en este momento.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  trabajador INT,
  fecha_siniestro DATETIME,
  meses_punibles INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id,trabajador,fecha_siniestro,meses_punibles) VALUES (1,11,'2019-05-12',5);
INSERT INTO test (id,trabajador,fecha_siniestro,meses_punibles) VALUES (1,22,'2019-01-12',3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE fecha_siniestro > NOW() - INTERVAL meses_punibles MONTH ;

| id  | trabajador | fecha_siniestro     | meses_punibles |
| --- | ---------- | ------------------- | -------------- |
| 1   | 11         | 2019-05-12 00:00:00 | 5              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar tan rapido!, pero siendote sincero no lo piyo, o estoy espero o soy muy inutil

Comment: Para buscar aquellos trabajadores con siniestros que afecten aun buscas si la fecha del siniestro es mayor de la fecha actual (now)  restándole los meses de penalización. En el ejemplo el trabajador que tuvo el siniestro en mayo aun está en penalización, el que lo tuvo en enero ya no.

Comment: Me dispongo a probarlo, ,a ver si me va bien muchas gracias! ahora te comento

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias! Estoy muy espeso esta semana!

Comment: Me alegro, para eso estamos ;)